# Netty Server handling multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets, client, netty

I want to set up a server that handles a calculation request. This calculation can be split up in x partial calculations so I want to have multiple clients that may register to the server. The server should have a list of these registered clients.

When the server receives a request it splits the calculation in its x parts and afterwards sends each calculation request to the clients and waits for the clients to end its calculation.

Does someone have an idea how to do this with netty or any other technology that may be easier? Netty seemed to be the right solution for me but I don't know how I can register and save the clients in the server and afterwards send the calculation parts to the clients and wait for them.

Comment: Writing the three or so dozen lines of code that are required to do this is probably a better choice than a "framework".

Comment: I don't think so as netty already handles some things that can occur like fragmentation and serialization. Also with netty I get very nice scalable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/) a try (distributed execution).

Comment: Can you explain how it works? How can I add members the the cluster that execute the Serializable Callable?

Comment: Simply by starting another node (be it on the same computer or on another one). They should find each other automatically.

Comment: Also you might want to take a look at the Documentation http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp and the ClusterTestHowto http://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/wiki/ClusterTestHowTo. Hope that helps.